# Display pie chart labels connected with lines outside the graph using Google Visualization API

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to get a pie chart to use labels connected with lines to the different slices using  Google Visualization API?

From what I understand, this is done by default using google image charts api:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = {
      legend: { position: 'labeled' }
  };
```